# DC motor control algorithm with low sample rate

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, pid-controller

I have a system driven by a geared DC motor spinning at between 500 and 1000 RPM. Once in operation, the load on the motor will not change and the speed should be held constant.

I have a single digital Hall-effect sensor sampling the output of the system once per rotation. Most PID controllers I’ve seen have much higher sampling rates. Will a traditional PID or PI controller work here? Are there alternative control algorithms I could use?

Additional context: The motor is driving a linearly reciprocating mechanism. The load will vary within a cycle, but the average load per cycle should be constant during operation (i.e. no external forces acting on the system aside from friction and air resistance). Speed variation should be less than 1%. I can’t place more than one sensor due to space restrictions and a limited number of available IO pins on my microcontroller.

Comment: Depends on how fast you need your PID to react on load changes

Comment: Load should be relatively stable once the machine is in operation. I need a controller that can spin a motor up to a target RPM and hold it at that exact speed. The precision here is much more important than the response time.

Comment: With a long integration time, your PID can be stable- however the regulation will be realy bad during start-up and load variations (even slight ones). A trick could be, do ramp the motor without regulation to lets say 75% of the target RPM and then activate the PID. Also, could you please define "Load should be relatively stable" and "hold it at that exact speed" it %-Terms? A simpler way is to increase the number of hall pulses (I assume digital once per rotation) - talk with your mechanical guys if this is possible

Comment: Generally trying to fix a bad sensor with a control algorithm will lead to disappointing results and a lot of time spent. Your sample rate is  8Hz-16Hz approximately, assuming you're using period, which might not be too low, depending on how the load varies. There are inexpensive rotary encoders that will output many (100 to 1000) pulses per revolution- generally quadrature but if you don't need direction you can ignore one of the outputs. You could also consider measuring the motor current and using that to feed forward, in addition to the sensor, but more pulses is easy.

Comment: Is the hall sensor sampling the motor speed? Or a shaft after all gearing takes place?

Comment: It’s actually sampling the reciprocating effector, but yes it would be after all the gearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discrete-time PID will do it. Sampling rate doesn't matter all that much, as long as there is no aliasing. In your case, the sensing point is always at the same mechanical angle, so it's probably fine. The upper end of the regulator bandwidth will be pretty low - a couple of Hz, say 2..4Hz.

Most likely you won't need the D term unless there's a structural resonance, and even then you'd only want to enable that term within the RPM range of structural resonance.

Do mind, though, that for stability you may end up interpolating between 2-3 sets of P,I,D coefficients, based on RPM.

Say that there's a structural resonance at 750RPM. You'd do one tuning at 500RPM, call it PID<sub>500</sub>, another at 1000RPM, PID<sub>1000</sub> and then at 750RPM where the resonance is - PID<sub>750</sub>. These parameter sets would be blended, using a set of blending functions, for example (Mathematica output):

[image]